# Title color for figure (not axes) in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Edit:** *Solution below, original question misses a bit of key information*

I am having difficulties changing the title color for my figure in Matplotlib.

I have a figure containing subplots:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax  = plt.subplots(3, 4, sharex='all', sharey='all',
                        figsize=(20, 9), dpi=600)
```

The figure has 10 subplots with data using the same symbols on each plot, so I want a joint legend for the figure, not for each axis.

I have blanked the upper right and middle right axes - I want the legend to go here:

```
ax[0,3].axis('off')
ax[1,3].axis('off')
```

I've created my legend elements:

```
legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], marker='x', color='w', markeredgecolor='b', label='Measured data points'),
                   Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='w', markeredgecolor='g', label='Means of data points'),
                   Line2D([0], [0], color='r', label='Curve fitted to model')]
```

When writing my legend, I'm having real difficulty changing the color of the title text. I have tried the following examples:

```
legend = fig.legend(handles=legend_elements, fontsize=10, labelcolor='c',
                    loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.77, 0.63, 1, 1))
legend.set_title('Legend\n', color='c')

TypeError: Legend.set_title() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color'
```

...

```
legend = fig.legend(handles=legend_elements, fontsize=10, labelcolor='c',
                    loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.77, 0.63, 1, 1),
                    title='Legend\n', title_fontsize=10)
plt.setp(legend.get_title(), color='c')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_title'
```

...

```
fig.setp(legend.get_title(), color='c')

AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'setp'
```

...

```
legend._legend_title_box._text.set_color('c')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_legend_title_box'
```

I've also looked at [FontProperties](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/font_manager_api.html#matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties), something along the lines of the following, but FontProperties doesn't have a color kwarg as far as I can tell:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

legend_title_props = font_manager.FontProperties(color='c')

legend = fig.legend(handles=legend_elements, fontsize=10, labelcolor='c',
                    loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.77, 0.63, 1, 1),
                    title='Legend\n', title_fontsize=10, 
                    title_fontproperties=legend_title_props)

TypeError: FontProperties.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color'
```

Does anyone have a workaround? I can't seem to find any other options online. I've got a feeling it stems from the fact that my legend is being stored as a 'NoneType' object, but I can't work out what I'm doing wrong to cause this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to this. I'll pop it here in case anyone else comes across the problem.

I had simplified the example somewhat from my original code, to make the question more clear. One of the simplifications I had done was remove some style editing that followed the legend, which turned out to be a fairly critical omission. The original statement in my code looked something like this, which resulted in legend being a NoneType object

```
legend = fig.legend().get_frame().set_boxstyle('Round')
```

I've now altered the code to the following which fixes things.

```
legend = fig.legend(handles=legend_elements, fontsize=10, labelcolor='c',
                    loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.77, 0.63, 1, 1),
                    title='Legend\n', title_fontsize=10)

plt.setp(legend.get_title(), color='c')
legend.get_frame().set_boxstyle('Round')
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Legend.get_title()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_api.html#matplotlib.legend.Legend.get_title) and [`Text.set_color()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_color):

```
legend = fig.legend(handles=legend_elements, fontsize=10, labelcolor='c',
                    loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.77, 0.63, 1, 1), 
                    title='Legend\n')
legend.get_title().set_color('c')
```

Output:

[image]

Note that both `plt.setp(legend.get_title(), color='c')` and `legend._legend_title_box._text.set_color('c')` also worked for me, so I'm not sure at what point `legend` became `NoneType`. It's clear that `fig.legend()` returns a `Legend` instance.

Comment: Thanks for this. Made me realise what I'd done wrong. I've edited the question and am closing it now.

Comment: Good point, done that now